# Very wide thin curly braces with CSS or jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

Is there a way to get very wide but thin *curly braces* with CSS / jQuery?

Simply scaling the `div` also scales the line width, so the braces become ugly when getting too big.

```
<div id="braces" style="font-size:20px;">{</div>

$("#braces").css({
    "transform" : "scale(4,25)"
});
```

This code gives me very very large and narrow curly braces, but I would like to have very thin braces where only the "arms" became longer.

Has anyone an idea of how to achieve that?

Comment: Can't you use the `{` character and change the font / font-size to achieve the desired result? It'll be much easier for us to help if you could share some code showing what you've already tried, and perhaps a sample of what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: You can try image for this or try 'font-size: 120px;

Comment: How can something be wide and thin at the same time?

Comment: @Holybreath I would like the braces be be very wide, but the thickness of the line to stay thin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution I used in the end is http://jsfiddle.net/q9Bcb/69/

```
    var height = canvas.height;
    var space  = 5;
    var radius = 7;

    var linelength = height / 2;

    context.lineWidth = 4;
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(20+radius, space);
    context.arcTo(20, space, 20, space+radius, radius);

    context.lineTo(20, linelength - radius);
    context.arcTo(20, linelength, 20 - radius, linelength, radius);
    context.arcTo(20, linelength, 20, linelength + radius, radius);
    context.lineTo(20, height - space - radius);
    context.arcTo(20, height - space, 20 + radius, height - space, radius);

    context.stroke();
```

Answer (score 6):

I'm not good at HTML / CSS, but I did my best.

```css
.brace {
  width: 2em;
  height: 3em;
}
.brace_part1 {
  border-left: 2px solid black;
  border-top-left-radius: 12px;
  margin-left: 2em;
}
.brace_part2 {
  border-right: 2px solid black;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 12px;
}
.brace_part3 {
  border-right: 2px solid black;
  border-top-right-radius: 12px;
}
.brace_part4 {
  border-left: 2px solid black;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 12px;
  margin-left: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div class="brace brace_part1"></div>
<div class="brace brace_part2"></div>
<div class="brace brace_part3"></div>
<div class="brace brace_part4"></div>
```

Comment: Here it to play with: https://jsfiddle.net/xabg9L3z/ . I like your elegant brackets, it is not yet easy usable, but that should be possible to get (see my jsfiddle to compare the usage of the div.

Answer (score 3):

It's pretty unorthodox and very ugly, but you could repeat the curly brace and offset each one to the left by a pixel each time:

**HTML**

```
<span id="cont"><span>}</span><span>}</span><span>}</span></span>
```

**CSS**

```
#cont{position:relative; font-size:32px;}
#cont span{position:absolute;top:0; left:0;}
#cont span:nth-child(2){left:1px}
#cont span:nth-child(3){left:2px}
```

Like I said, really ugly and very hacky. But I don't think there is a way of upping the 'thickness' - except for bold which is limited.

[<kbd>JSFiddle</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/fp5hF/3/)

Or use jQuery to do it for you:

```
$orig = $('#orig');
for(i=0;i<5;i++){
    $orig.clone().css({left:i+1}).appendTo($('#cont'));
}
```

With the `for()` limit being the number of times to copy the curly brace across.

[<kbd>JSFiddle</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/fp5hF/2/)

Comment: Do you see a similar solution for vertically long braces? I played with partially covering span's by others, but nothing looked nice -- Thanks!