# Insert text to the left of a blockquote

Tags: html, css, blockquote

I'm following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20941993/1086511) to insert a curly bracket before two fields in my form (there's a jsfiddle in the link):

[image: two fields with * in the wrong place]

The red * means that field is required. But actually, the user could supply one OR the other, so the proper representation would be:

[image: two fields with * in the right place]

But since the { comes from a `<blockquote>` tag, I don't know how to add the * there, to the left of the picture (unless it's part of the picture, but that's a sub-optimal solution, because in different computers the font will be different). The fields are part of a definition list, with the label in the `<dt>` and the input in the `<dd>` part.

Perhaps the solution is not to use a `<blockquote>` at all?

Comment: The content doesn't *look* like a quotation

Comment: It's NOT a quotation. It's just a way to show that at least one of the fields should be filled. I'm accepting suggestions.

Comment: Can you provide the html and css you are using for that section? Maybe even recreate it in a fiddle?

Comment: If it isn't a quotation then you should not use blockquote because that means "This is a quotation".

Comment: @hopkins-matt, although the fiddle given (in the link) is not exactly the same, I think the solution will be the same. If you think it won't, tell me and I'll provide it.

Comment: @Quentin, you have a better idea?

Comment: Fieldset maybe. There's rarely much point trying to recommend semantics based on a context free picture of a fragment of a document.

Comment: Yes, if I don't get an answer here, fieldset will be the way to go. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Daniel suggested the `:before` pseudo element is our friend here. But he did not bother to move the asterisk down to the middle. In my example, it is not perfectly vertically aligned, but I believe this is due to the curly brace image used.

**CSS:**

```
blockquote {
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:1px 0 1px 20px;
    border-image:url(http://opbokken.nu/meuk/curly.png) 1 20 stretch;
    padding-left:0.5em;
    position: relative;
}

blockquote:before {
  content: "*";
  color: red;
  margin-left: calc((30px + 0.5em) * -1);
  top: 50%;
  position: absolute;
}
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/hopkins_matt/xc59ejrj/

The correct `top` for the above example would be `top: calc(50% - 5px);`

Comment: It works if I have only one bracket. As I have two, only the second * appears, unless I remove the "position: absolute". But in this case, the * goes to the top again...

Comment: Make a fiddle with your example and I can take a look. You can use the `nth-of-type()` selector to target only one curly brace.

Comment: Wait till my team decide what appearance they like more. If they choose fieldset, then that's it!

Comment: Yes, they've chosen fieldset. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2):

If you use the `:before` pseudo-selector, you can add content before the start of the `blockquote`. Got the base code from the example you refered to.

CSS

```
blockquote {
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:1px 0 1px 20px;
    border-image:url(http://opbokken.nu/meuk/curly.png) 1 20 stretch;
    padding-left:0.5em;
}

blockquote:before {
  content: '*';
  color: red;
  margin: -50px;
}
```

HTML

```
<blockquote>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Si longus, levis. Aliter autem vobis placet. Confecta res esset. Cyrenaici quidem non recusant; Duo Reges: constructio interrete. Tum mihi Piso: Quid ergo? </p>

<p>Ut aliquid scire se gaudeant? Eadem fortitudinis ratio reperietur. </p>

<p>Huius ego nunc auctoritatem sequens idem faciam. Sed plane dicit quod intellegit. Nulla erit controversia. Ad eas enim res ab Epicuro praecepta dantur. </p>
</blockquote>
```

Working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5tCrE/57/

Comment: It's almost there. The * should be in the vertical center of the {